# How to make Sharepoint custom form using Powerapps as Modal Dialog Box

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have Sharepoint 365 Powerapps CustomForm.
How do I make the form as modal dialog, when the user click outside of the form, the form NOT disappeared !!
Like if you select multi items and click on edit, you get dialog mode (but not powerapps form).
Is there a way to prevent the user from clicking outside the form?
[image]
Thanks
Amit